# Changing background-position-x on :hover

Tags: css, hover, selection

I am trying to get a little hover animation going by moving the background image on the x-axis. However, I can't seem to find how to capture the element:hover. Does anyone has an idea what is wrong? Is the selector below valid?

Thank you for your help

```
 div.card:hover .cardbg {

}
```

```css
.card {
border-radius:15px;
border:none;
height: 280px;
position: relative;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffec99 0,#ffb549 100%);
z-index: -1;
font-family: 'Arial';
}

.cardbg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('images/atom-original.svg');
 opacity: 0.2;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position-x: 100px;
 transition: .2s ease all;
 position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div.card:hover .cardbg {
background-position-x: 10px;
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<div class="cardbg">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `z-index: -1` from the `.card` class. That worked for me.

Comment: @SaroVerhees Hey thanks! If you could mark the answer as correct that would be awesome!

Comment: You got it buddy!